# Curl Put Request: content-type header is not supported

Tags: json, bash, curl

Trying to work through a demo with Elastic for setting the mapping with JSON. Operating in Ubuntu LTS and keep running into issues with the request.

**Original Issue:**

```sh
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/stub" -d "{"test"}"
```

Returns an error:

```
curl: (3) Failed to convert “localhost to ACE; string contains a disallowed character
```

I have tried changing without a port to test and still get the same result. Same with trying single quotes and 127.0.0.1

Any idea what I could be missing?

**Update:** corrected the quotation mark irregularities, still having issues.

```sh
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/stub" -d "{"test"}"
```

Returns an error:

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

Comment: now it's a problem with the server you're talking to. the appropriate thing to do is to consult the server/api's documentation, but i have a hunch, try: ```curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/stub' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"test":1}'``` , what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have typographic quotes (`“”`) in the command. In Bash (and all other POSIX shells as far as I know) those are treated as *literal* rather than syntactic characters, so they become part of the `curl` argument.

This is typically caused by bad blog software + copy-pasting code from third parties, both of which should be avoided.

Comment: Yeah it seems there were some errant quotation marks, thank you. Updated with new error.